# Modify colors for up-vote and down-vote arrow

Tags: feature-request, design, votes

I'm color blind, and I have a hard time distinguishing between the neutral and pressed up and down vote colors. I have already had my votes locked on a few questions by trying to up-vote them when they were already up-voted. Does anyone else have this problem?

Could the contrast between these colors be increased or a boarder added to help distinguish between voted and non-voted questions and answers.

Comment: +1 too. Perhaps while this feature gets implemented, you could try to customize the css/html for the vote arrows in the PC you use the most. Something like [this](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/could-we-change-the-color-of-the-accepted-answer-check-for-color-blind-people/1702#1702).